# Android SQLite Database Foreign Key Does Not Work

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm working with the Android SQLite Database and I have two Tables in it.

Table `CHECKPOINTS` defines a foreign key to an attribute in Table `TOUR`.

After storing data to the database the table `Tour` is displayed correctly. But, the column with the foreign key `TOUR_ID` in table `CHECKPOINTS` remains blank. I don't know why.

The syntax should be ok and I also set the `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`.
After experimenting a while I defined a `Trigger` in the `onCreate()` function of my `DatabaseHelper`.

But, now I get an Error:

`android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`.

DatabaseHelper:

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE_TOUR = "create table TOUR("
        + " ID integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + " NAME varchar(20)) ";


private static final String TABLE_CREATE_CHECKPOINT = "create table CHECKPOINT("
        + " ID integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + " TOUR_ID integer not null, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY (TOUR_ID) REFERENCES TOUR(ID)) ";


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_TOUR);
    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_CHECKPOINT);

    database.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_checkpoint_tourid BEFORE INSERT ON CHECKPOINT "
                    + " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN "
                    + " SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT ID FROM TOUR WHERE ID = new.TOUR_ID ) IS NULL) "
                    + " THEN RAISE (ABORT, 'Foreign Key Violation') END; "
                    + " END;");

}
```

DataSource:

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Enable foreign key constraints
    if (!database.isReadOnly()) {
         database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    } 
}
```

Does anyone have an idea, on how to get this thing going ?

EDIT:

Insert in Table `TOUR`:

```
    public long InsertTour(String name){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("NAME", name);

    return database.insert("TOUR", null, values);       
}
```

The Table `CHECKPOINT` contains more data as described above. Here's the insert:

```
public Entry createEntry(String PARAM1, String PARAM2, long PARAM3, String PARAM4) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("COLUMN1", PARAM1);
    values.put("COLUMN2", PARAM2);
    values.put("COLUMN3", PARAM3);
    values.put("COLUMN4", PARAM4);

    long insertId = database.insert("CHECKPOINT", null, values);

    Cursor cursor = database.query("CHECKPOINT", allColumns, "ID = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursorToEntry(cursor);
}
```

Comment: it is all implemented. i edited the question.

Comment: 1) Why are you inserting 4 values into CHECKPOINT when it has 2 columns?  2) Why are you using inexistent column names?  3) What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: ... as is said: "the table CHECKPOINT contains more data than described above". It actually has the columns ID, TOUR_ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4. ID is autoincrement und TOUR_ID should be filled via foreign key. i just shortened the code before i posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat difficult to tell what's wrong because you are not giving the complete details but from your answers I think you have the wrong concept about foreign keys and you are expecting something to be automatically "*filled via foreign key*".

Foreign key constraints are used to enforce **exists** relationships between tables. That is, you would not be able to insert a `checkpoint` row having a `tour_id` that doesn't exist on `tour` table.

Read more at http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: yeah i think you're right. I misunderstood something. Thanks for sharing the link, i will read it carefully!